# Como exportar una tabla html a un archivo excel en firefox?

Tags: javascript, html5, excel

Buen día encontré un codigo de javascript que te permite generar un archivo excel a partir de una tabla de html, el problema que solo funciona en google chrome, quisiera también poder usarlo en firefox o en otro navegador.

```
function descargarExcel(variable_conTabla){
    //Creamos un Elemento Temporal en forma de enlace
    var tmpElemento = document.createElement('a');
    // obtenemos la información desde el div que lo contiene en el html

    // Obtenemos la información de la tabla
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tabla_div = variable_conTabla;
    var tabla_html = tabla_div.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    tmpElemento.href = data_type + ', ' + tabla_html;
    //Asignamos el nombre a nuestro EXCEL
    tmpElemento.download = 'Nombre_De_Mi_Excel.xls';
    // Simulamos el click al elemento creado para descargarlo
    tmpElemento.click();
}
```

El código funciona bien, pero además que no sirve en firefox, exportar en un formato de excel 1997, y tampoco exporta las tildes de las palabras. Podrían ayudarme a solucionarlo. aquí les dejo imagenes de como exporta las tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<table id="tablita" class="table table-striped" style:'margin:="" 0="" auto;'=""> <thead class="thead-light align-middle"> <tr><th scope="col">Cuota</th><th scope="col">Fecha de Cuota</th><th scope="col">Dias de diferencia</th><th scope="col">Dias de diferencia acumulado</th><th scope="col">Vector Mensual</th><th scope="col">Cuota del mes</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>Lunes 1 de Abril del 2019</td><td>28</td><td>28</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>MiÃ©rcoles 1 de Mayo del 2019</td><td>30</td><td>58</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Sabado 1 de Junio del 2019</td><td>31</td><td>89</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Lunes 1 de Julio del 2019</td><td>30</td><td>119</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>Jueves 1 de Agosto del 2019</td><td>31</td><td>150</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>Domingo 1 de Septiembre del 2019</td><td>31</td><td>181</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>Martes 1 de Octubre del 2019</td><td>30</td><td>211</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>Viernes 1 de Noviembre del 2019</td><td>31</td><td>242</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td>Domingo 1 de Diciembre del 2019</td><td>30</td><td>272</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>MiÃ©rcoles 1 de Enero del 2020</td><td>31</td><td>303</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>Sabado 1 de Febrero del 2020</td><td>31</td><td>334</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>12</td><td>Domingo 1 de Marzo del 2020</td><td>29</td><td>363</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>MiÃ©rcoles 1 de Abril del 2020</td><td>31</td><td>394</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>14</td><td>Viernes 1 de Mayo del 2020</td><td>30</td><td>424</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr><tr><td>15</td><td>Lunes 1 de Junio del 2020</td><td>31</td><td>455</td><td>1</td><td>810.79379</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

esto me sale abriendolo en wordpad
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al ejecutarlo en firefox no hace nada, la consola no arroja ningun error ni nada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El archivo xls que te tira error, ábrelo con un editor de texto sencillo, te recomiendo notepad++ y muéstrame qué sale, para ver si te puedo ayudar.

Comment: Ya añadi, lo que me muestra, y un pantallazo de lo que se ve en wordpad

Comment: le falta la cabecera

Comment: Aparentemente no te está generando el excel en absoluto, veamos qué error sale cuando colocas inspeccionar elemento en el explorador al momento de generar el excel.

Comment: Debe haber algún error en Console en el explorador.

Comment: la verdad es que no arrojada nada en la consola

Comment: versiones antiguas de excel tomaban un html `<table></table>` renombrado como `.xls` directamente, las nuevas versiones necesitan la cabecera con el schema fijate este snippet https://stackoverflow.com/a/47586241/1423096